# How to add dirs with spaces to PATH in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, minted, python

In order to use the minted package from within TeXstudio 3.0.1, I am trying to add the directory where my python.exe and my pygmentize.exe are to my PATH from within TeXstudio.  If I do this using the Windows Environment Variable settings, it works.  However, if I do this by going to 'Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Build' and then after 'Commands ($PATH)' enter the following

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts
```

this fails: neither python.exe nor pygmentize.exe are found.  I tried putting stuff between double quotes, escaping the space character,... but couldn't get it to work.
What is the exact syntax to add multiple directories that can include spaces to the PATH from within that TeXstudio option?

Comment: Have you tried the standard trick: `"..."` around the entire path

Comment: Yes.  Both "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts" did not work.

Comment: I know nothing of texstudio but if all else fails you could use the old 8+3 DOS name as shown by `dir /x` so on my machine at least I could replace `c:\Program Files (x86)` by `c:\PROGRA~2`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.  Apparently, there was a directory

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

rather at the beginning of my PATH.  This directory contains a strange Python.exe file of 0 bytes, which fires up the Microsoft Store (at the page where you can download the Python app):

```
C:\>dir C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\*.exe
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is AE85-9C04

 Directory of C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

26/02/2020  08:07                 0 MicrosoftEdge.exe
31/12/2020  19:42                 0 python.exe
31/12/2020  19:42                 0 python3.exe
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  110.686.470.144 bytes free
```

Since the paths that I configured only got added at the *end* of my PATH environment variable, it was this strange Python.exe file that got called first.

Removing the 'Application execution aliases' for python.exe and python3.exe from my Settings, as eplained on https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor solved the problem.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485491/python-python3-executes-in-command-prompt-but-does-not-run-correctly for some extra info.